# pygsheets get_all_records value_render = FORMULA is casting as int

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

I'm trying to pull data and formulas out of a Google Sheet using pygsheets and get_all_records method.  Source data looks like this where cell B2 is =A2*3.

```
Number  Formula                                                                                             
11.5    34.5
```

When I use get_all_values method, I get the correct results.

```
cellVals = ws.get_all_values(include_tailing_empty = False, value_render = pygsheets.custom_types.ValueRenderOption.FORMULA) 
    print(cellVals)

[['Number', 'Formula'], [11.5, '=A2*3']]
```

But when I use get_all_records, cell A1 gets cast as an int

```
cellRecs = ws.get_all_records(value_render = pygsheets.custom_types.ValueRenderOption.FORMULA)     print(cellRecs)

[{'Number': 11, 'Formula': '=A2*3'}]
```

I would love to not have to build a workaround.  Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, how about using a parameter of `numericise_data` as follows? [Ref](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet.html?highlight=get_all_records#pygsheets.Worksheet.get_all_records)

```
cellRecs = ws.get_all_records(value_render=pygsheets.custom_types.ValueRenderOption.FORMULA, numericise_data=False)
```

- When I tested the this modification for your sample value, the following result is obtained.

  ```
    [{'Number': 11.5, 'Formula': '=A2*3'}]
  ```